# Two of the same characters turn to uppercase instead of just one python

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to manipulate a word by upper casing each character in an array, but when it comes to a word that has two of the same character it makes them both capitalized instead of just one.  Not a programmer just trying to learn python.  Thank in advance!

```
answer = raw_input("What is your word? ")
x = 0
answerWord = ''.join(answer)
while (x < len(answer)):
    if (answerWord[x] != answerWord[x].upper()):
        letter = answerWord.replace(answer[x], answer[x].upper())
    print letter
    x = x + 1

What is your word? boot
Boot
bOOt
bOOt
booT

What is your word? crazy
Crazy
cRazy
crAzy
craZy
crazY
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
answer = raw_input("What is your word? ")

for char in range(len(answer)):
    letter = answer[0:char] + answer[char].upper() + answer[char+1:]
    print letter
```

That should do the thing, it changes every letter to upper case one by one, and then prints them. Also, in your example, if you take a word that already has uppercase letters ('Peanuts', for example) it will raise an error, since the the "if" sentence is not True, and therefore `letter` would be undefined.

If you want uppercase letters to go lowercase, and lowercase letters to go uppercase, or such, use this:

```
answer = raw_input("What is your word? ")

for char in range(len(answer)):
    if answer[char] == answer[char].lower():
        letter = answer[0:char] + answer[char].upper() + answer[char+1:]
    else:
        letter = answer[0:char] + answer[char].lower() + answer[char+1:]
    print letter
```

Also note, that if you're not going to use `letter` for anything other than printing it, you could just replace both of the letter definitions with simply a print, and remove the `print letter` completely.

```
if answer[char] == answer[char].lower():
    print answer[0:char] + answer[char].upper() + answer[char+1:]
else:
    print answer[0:char] + answer[char].lower() + answer[char+1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

`answerWord.replace('X', 'Y')` will replace *all* instances of `X` with `Y` in your string.  So line 6 of your program takes the entire word `answerWord`, and replaces all instances of the letter it is currently considering with its uppercase equivalent.

It seems from your variable names that you intended the variable `letter` to be the single letter, rather than the whole word. Perhaps you meant line 6 to read something like:

```
letter = answer[x].upper()
```

Have fun!

Comment: That does work but it only prints the one letter and not the whole word, so now it shows up as: 

`What is your word? crazy 
C 
R 
A 
Z 
Y`

Can't get the format to work, but it puts c on one line and then a on the next line and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(answer)):
    print answer[0:i]+answer[i].upper()+answer[i+1:]
```